# Retrieving data from database and displaying on web page not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database called `resources` and a table inside that database called `resources`. I am trying to display some content and having some trouble.  This is the code I am using:

```php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'resources');
$query   = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM resources WHERE iss = 1 ORDER BY added DESC');
$company = 'company';
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "Company: " . $rows[$company];
}
```

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM resources . resources`

Comment: also, mysql is deprecated, no longer supported and may be insecure. You should use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Hmmm i tried out your suggestions and still no luck.  It loads my footer and title but still no content... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need to properly open that `div` tag.
2. You need to select a database using `mysql_select_db`, not by adding the fourth parameter to `mysql_connect`.

This all also assumes your connections are working properly and everything is installed fine. Then, you should be able to get it working with something closer to this:

```
<div id="section_content">
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
    mysql_select_db('resources');
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM resources WHERE iss = 1 ORDER BY added DESC');
    $company = 'company';
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo "Company: " .$rows[$company];
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was very helpful.  I didnt know that i didnt need that extra parameter.  Once i moved it to "mysql_select_db" it started working.  Thank you so much!